# UIImageView rotation (NOT the image, but the view)

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiimageview, rotation

How do I rotate the ImageView ... i'm trying to use landscape mode, and have a problem with accelerometer moving the image ...
Because when I work in portrait mode the x of accelerometer is the same as the x of the image ... But when I work landscape, the x of accelerometer is the y of the image, because the ImageView autorotates with the parent View.
When I rotate the image with CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2), it rotates only the image in it's ImageView... and the x,y sides stays untouched ...
Is there any way to make own class which will extend UIImageView where I will swap the x,y sides of a UIImageView ?
Or is there some way to rotate the UIImageView, and not only the image in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert points depending on orientation...

```
if( orientation == LANDSCAPE )
{

   CGPoint temp;

  temp = [touch locationInView:self];

  touchPoint.x = temp.y;

  touchPoint.y = 320 - temp.x;

}
```

The above code convert points from portrait to landscape...

Answer (score 0):

```
float degree = atan2(accelX, accelY) * 180 / 3.14159;
```

where accelX and accelY are the values from the accelerometer, use the degree and rotate the ImageView.

Comment: can u please post some example ?
Don't know if i understand it ... :(

Comment: dont know if you understand me correctly ... i want to rotate it exactly by 90 degree, but NOT only the image in the ImageView, but want to somehow swap x and y of the UIImageView ...